# Connecting to integrated SQL Server in Visual Studio 2016

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, oledb, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use `OLE DB` to connect to the SQL Server that shipped with VS2015 (this should be SQL Server Express I think). Actually I have problems getting my connection string set up. All my attempts resulted in a generic error message.

The errors occurred with this line of code afterwards:

```
oCon = New OleDbConnection(cConnectstring)
```

I tried following connection strings:

```
Server=localhost;Database=main_Table;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

As well as:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Initial Catalog=main_Table;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Or:

```
Provider = sqloledb;Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = main_Table;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

where `main_Table` is the table I try to start with. I used the connection string that I get via right click on that table in the DB explorer as well (that worked for my Access DBs flawlessly).

Does anybody know how to make this work with Ole DB and SQL Server 2016?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use OleDb for this? Use the native driver (SqlClient) unless you have a very good reason not to, especially as MS is retiring OleDb.

Comment: There is (almost) no such thing as a `generic error message`.  There are words telling you whats wrong so you can fix it.

Comment: As @Joel said, you'd want to use the [SQL connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx).  I use OleDb/OleDb connection for Microsoft Access applications.